# Importing colour map from .text file which will then correspond to geologic shapefile on QGIS 3.10.6

Tags: qgis, style, color, text

I have been searching for this solution for over a week now and have tried many of the suggested solutions online but so far northing has worked. I have a Geology vector layer and a corresponding RGB text file which has the appropriate colour values.

I have tried using the `Setting > Style Manager > Import`. This requires an xml file which I made from the text file but I am met with the following error when I attempt to import it.

```
Incorrect root tag in style: w:wordDocument
```

I have also attempted using the Style tab in the Symbology section of the Layer Properties but this method requires a qml or sld file.

I have attempted to import the txt file to the layer tree and then save the style as a qml and import the saved style. I am met with the following error.

```
Cannot apply style with symbology to layer with different geometry type
```

The geology shapefile geometry is Polygon (MultiPloygon)

I have spent a few days attempting the various Python solutions but I have zero experience with Python and those attempts have gotten me no where.

Here is an example of the text file I am uploading:

```
Value,Red,Green,Blue  
63,   227, 215, 164  
61,   90,  134, 103  
60,   109, 167, 133  
59,   122, 181, 139
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a sample of the file(s) you are trying to import as style? What geometry type is your vector layer (Polygon? LineString?)?

Comment: Okay will do thank you